Calculating the Least Squares Error for a model
I've been doing a bit of self-study and came across this question. I have looked into LSE questions but I genuinely don't understand how this works. Could someone give me a brief idea on how to solve this? I've been stuck on figuring this out with no luck.


If you're having trouble with implementing the least squares method then you should post some code and explain your problem in detail. If you just don't understand the method at all then it's not a programming problem (yet). Ask on [maths.se], or perhaps [Stats.se]
